# Same .htaccess rules doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to rewrite url for two pages like that:

Original:

http://example.com/team.php?PAGE=profile&LINK=jenifer

http://example.com/course.php?PAGE=view&LINK=dance

Desired:

http://example.com/jenifer

http://example.com/dance

I tried with this rules

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /team.php?PAGE=profile&LINK=$1 [L]

 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /course.php?PAGE=view&LINK=$1 [L]
```

I don't know why only the first page is rewrited corectly and the second page is rewrited as the first page too.

Also, my index.php is redirected to team.php

Thank you!

Comment: That cannot work. Pretty URL scheme should have some identifier for php handler as well. Something like `http://example.com/team/jenifer` and `http://example.com/course/dance` would be better.

Comment: Even if the first page works if i remove the second rule? Cause it works.

Comment: Just keeping a single rule as `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /team.php?PAGE=profile&LINK=$1 [L,QSA]` will work but it cannot work for both rules since pattern is same.

Comment: Your first rule says "match anything not in a subfolder and rewrite to the team.php page and then don't process any rules afterward." Because both of your rewrite rules have the same pattern match, the second one will never be hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset) looks at each rule in turn, until it finds a matching one.

Take for example `http://example.com/jenifer`, where the request for `jenifer` is matched against the first rule pattern `^([^/]*)$`. And look at `http://example.com/dance`, here again `dance` is matched against the first rule pattern `^([^/]*)$`. The second rule is never tried, because the first one already swallows each request.

When you have a request matching the pattern `^([^/]*)$`, Apache will always stop at the first `RewriteRule`, because this is the first matching one.

---

If you want to distinguish between team members and courses, you must also have different patterns to match against, as @anubhava already suggested in the comments, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^team/([^/]*)$ /team.php?PAGE=profile&LINK=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^course/([^/]*)$ /course.php?PAGE=view&LINK=$1 [L]
```

Now, when you get a request for `http://example.com/team/jenifer` or `http://example.com/course/dance`, Apache is able to select the proper rule because of the leading `team` or `course` in the requests.